# When replacing a file in Firebase Storage, how can I tell when the new version is available for download?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

When I upload a file (in my case, a photo), with the same name as an existing file, to Firebase Storage, it replaces the one that's there, which is what I want.  But I'm also writing a record to Firebase Realtime Database which triggers a Cloud Function that downloads and generates thumbnails for the newly overwritten file.  There are times when the Cloud Function seems to retrieve the previous version, probably because the CDN or other caching layers haven't updated yet.

I thought about putting a 500ms delay before I trigger the Cloud Function, but that seems fragile.  Is there any way to tell for sure when the new version of the photo has propagated, and will be the one that is downloaded?